# postcss lost grid support webpack2?

Tags: webpack, webpack-2, postcss

I am having issue with 'lost grid', I just couldn't get it work on webpack2 for some reason, is there anyone having success?

Using `"webpack": "^2.2.1","lost": "^8.0.0","postcss": "^5.2.16",`

```
     {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'style-loader',
          },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              importLoaders: 1,
              // modules: true,
              // localIdentName: '[folder]--[local]--[hash:base64:2]',
            }
          },
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
              plugins: () => [
                require('autoprefixer')({
                  browsers: [
                    '>1%',
                    'last 4 versions',
                    'Firefox ESR',
                    'not ie < 9', // React doesn't support IE8 anyway
                  ],
                }),
                require('lost'),
              ],
            },
          },
        ],
      },
```

I did even refer to create react app webpack config.

https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.dev.js

Answer (score 0):

I was in the same boat. I just fixed the issue. The running project is hosted at https://github.com/hhimanshu/iamlost.
There were 2 things to be done
- `npm run eject` to be able to see webpack configuration. Make sure to check-in the files in your repository.
- Then add one line as described in https://github.com/hhimanshu/iamlost/commit/7efe3803a14623ac7dd343fd5330d2d0effdd7cd

Hope that helps. You need to make changes in both webpack files - dev and prod